# Susy. Wrong margins for columns in fixed layout

Tags: sass, susy-sass, susy

I am making a fixed layout with Susy and stuck with this issue when the second column has a right margin even if I specify that they are nested within a container.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zGNOKK?editors=110)

HTML

```
<div class="control">
  <label class="control__label">Email</label>
  <input type="text" class="control__self">
</div>
```

CSS

```
@import "susy";

$fixed: (
  box-sizing: border-box,
  math: static,
  columns: 12,
  column-width: 60px,
  gutters: 20px/60px,
  gutter-poistion: inside
);

@include with-layout($fixed) {
  .control {
    @include container(12);
    .control__label {
      @include span(3 of 12);
    }
    .control__self {
      @include span(9 of 12);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed

```
.control__self {
  @include span(9 of 12);
}
```

to

```
.control__self {
  @include span(9 of 12 last nest);
}
```

and works like a charm.